# SQL Auto-Increment by DateTime

Tags: mysql, datetime, auto-increment

Is there a way in my sql to auto increment by the date and time?

so say I have a table

```
                         mytable
 =====================================================
 = Comment_ID = First_Name =  Comment  =  DateTime   =
 =====================================================
 =     1     =      Bob   =  FooBar = 11-01-14 11:00 =
 =     2     =     Jack   =  Blah   = 11-01-14 12:29 =
 =     3     =     John   =  jonny  = 12-01-14 07:09 =
 =====================================================
```

Is there away to make the date auto-increment?

Comment: not able to understand "date auto-increment"?

Comment: Auto increment in what sense? There is no built-in way to `auto-increment` date time, cause that field is something that a user defines. Tell me what language you using.

Comment: I want it so every time a new row is added the DATETIME field is auto incremented by the Current date and time

Comment: use `timestamp` for this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Could you explain further what time stamp is?

Comment: did you check the url?

Comment: Sorry I just saw that haha and thank you very much could you put that as an answer I think it would be helpful to others who where unaware of the timestamp as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this in your MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` 
CHANGE COLUMN `DateTime` `DateTime` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

This sets your default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default value for your datetime column, `now()`. This way whenever you add a row, it will automatically get current datetime.

Comment: did you mean row maybe ?