# Combining SQL statements

Tags: sql

I have the two below SQL queries.  They work fine individually w/n the same php script.  Would there be an advantage in combining them performance wise? If so, how is that done.  The COALESCE part has me stumped as I only want that column updated only once.

```
$sql_update = "INSERT INTO mobile_update(cust_id, last_name, first_name, dob) VALUES('$cust_id', '$last_name', '$first_name', '$dob') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_name = '$last_name', first_name = '$first_name', dob = '$dob';";
$sql_initial_entry = "UPDATE mobile_update set initial_entry = COALESCE(initial_entry, NOW()) where cust_id = '$cust_id';";
```

Comment: Why not a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$sql_initial_entry contains an update statement which only changes the values in an existing row (made in the previous statement). I can see no way to 'combine' these queries. I would think the only strategy that's viable is to set your initial_entry (seemd to be a date/timestamp)as an autoincrement column - like

```
ALTER TABLE `mobile_update' 
CHANGE COLUMN `initial_entry` `initial_entry` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

From:[SQL Auto-Increment by DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450914/sql-auto-increment-by-datetime)

This way you just pass a null in the insert statement and it will populate the current timestamp.
Coalesce just handles nulls with an alternate value. Allow nulls if you expect them.