# MySQL create an integer column that auto-updates to increment value

Tags: mysql, ddl

I'm wondering if I can do this without a trigger:

I want to have **an `INT` column** which is auto-updated to increment the integer value.

This is similar but not the same as `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column.

I read in the docs it's not possible with `ON UPDATE` because I can only use literal values unless the column is a `TIMESTAMP`.

[MySQL default and on update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#idm140652097075520)

[MySQL timestamp initialization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Can I do something else instead of a trigger?

**[UPDATE 1]**

This example is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    stuff VARCHAR (100),
    special_col INT DEFAULT 123456789
);

INSERT INTO myTable (stuff) VALUES ('something or other');

SELECT * FROM myTable;

stuff                 | special_col
----------------------------------------------------
something or other    | 123456789

UPDATE myTable SET stuff = 'new info';

SELECT * FROM myTable;

stuff                 | special_col
----------------------------------------------------
new info              | 123456790
```

The value that the column increments by doesn't have to be 1. It just has to be higher than before.

**[UPDATE 2]**

I thought there might be some cool mySQL syntax I could use - it does so much non-ANSI SQL, I figured there might be a custom way of doing it.

Anyway, I have given up and I'm implementing a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_data_update BEFORE UPDATE ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.special_col = OLD.special_col + 1;
```

Comment: what you mean auto-update increment value? can you show us an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Auto-Increment by DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450914/sql-auto-increment-by-datetime)

Comment: I have added an example and emphasised a couple of points to make it clear why this isn't a dupe. Would appreciate it if you could take the dupe flag off.

Comment: You cant, you need a trigger.

Comment: One day in the future maybe mySQL will bring out a version which allows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one to the special_col in the UPDATE as per [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE myTable SET stuff = 'new info', special_col=special_col+1;
```

Comment: That's unenforceable though.

Comment: To make enforceable it would have to be a TRIGGER.